# how to export database?I'm using teraterm

Tags: mysql, linux, teraterm

Does anybody know how to export database?

I'm using TeraTerm and i want to export the database for backup purpose. I tried searching on google about the command but i can't find it.

EDIT:

Thank you for your time and effort in answering my question.The database was already exported. I use this :

```
    mysqldump -u root -ptest test_db > backup.sql
```

Comment: Just use mysqldump command

Comment: See this [link](http://www.linuxtweaker.com/linux/how-to-export-and-import-mysql-database-via-command-line-in-linux/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `mysqldump` command this way:

```
mysqldump -u root -ptest test_db > backup.sql
```

Where username is `root`, root password is `test` and database name is `test_db`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mysql database, then there are numerous ways you can do that.
One is that you can set up 'phpmyadmin' on your server and export the database using the phpmyadmin web interface.
Or you can use this command:
"mysqldump -u [user] -p[password] [database-name]"  >  [database-export-file-name.sql]

Note that there is no space between -p and password.

See this for reference: http://www.itworld.com/article/2833078/it-management/3-ways-to-import-and-export-a-mysql-database.html